# Print MySQL results with PHP in spreadsheet form?

Tags: php, mysql

M code here just prints it like HTML, and I was wondering if there is a way to format into a HTML table like format with column names at the top

```
print "Skill ||| Pay Rate";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))
  {

    print "\n";
    print "$row[skill_Description], $row[skill_PayRate] ";
  }
```

I was looking into jquery but I'm really new at this

Comment: Look at using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to generate CSV format data

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
print "<table class='table'>\n\t<tr>\n";    
for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields ($res); $i++)
{       
    print "\t\t<th>".mysqli_fetch_field_direct ($res, $i)->name."</th>\n";      
}       
print "\t</tr>\n";

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($res)))
{
    print "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $val)
    {
        print "\t\t<td>".$val."</td>\n";
    }
    print "\t</tr>\n";
}   
print "</table>";
```